# Trigger jQuery event on Bootstrap data-show-columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In one of my projects I am using a Bootstrap table for displaying and manipulating data. I also use `data-show-columns="true"` in order to allow the user to show/hide needed columns in the table.

When it is used it messes up some of the styling in the table.

Is there any way that I can trigger the jQuery event or call JavaScript function when I use `data-show-columns` functionality of Bootstrap table?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/33/) is a good example of a table with `data-show-columns` functionality. It is not my code. All I need is to somehow trigger the jQuery event on columns show/hide.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$("#yourTableId").on("column-switch.bs.table", function() {
     ....
     ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.